# KMM: embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode error: Operation not permitted

Tags: xcode, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm encountering an error when trying to build the iOS app for my project in XCode. The gradle task fails:

```
Resolve mutations for :GCAppShared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode (Thread[#808,Execution worker,5,main]) started.
:GCAppShared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode (Thread[#808,Execution worker,5,main]) started.

> Task :GCAppShared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode FAILED
error: /Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GCiosApp-caesltabwlltiwgdsytbghwsxekm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GCiosApp.app/Frameworks: Operation not permitted

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':GCAppShared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode'.
> Cannot access output property 'destDir' of task ':GCAppShared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode'. Accessing unreadable inputs or outputs is not supported. Declare the task as untracked by using Task.doNotTrackState(). See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/incremental_build.html#disable-state-tracking for more details.
   > java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GCiosApp-caesltabwlltiwgdsytbghwsxekm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GCiosApp.app/Frameworks: Operation not permitted
```

It was working yesterday, even though I upgraded to MacOS Sonoma the day before, it's just hit out of the blue today. I've tried the usual things like "Clean Build Folder", deleting the project and checking out a pristine copy from git and deleting the `GCiosApp-...` folder refered to in the error message, but nothing works.

I suspect the part about state tracking relates to a symptom, not the cause. The link doesn't scroll to the relevant part of the page, which isn't particularly helpful anyway. Apparently I need to apply a `doNotTrackState()` method somewhere, but where? None of my project's gradle files have anything remotely like their example. I'm sure I don't want to apply it to the entire GCAppShared module, but the string "embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode" appears absolutely nowhere in the entire project folder.

This isn't the first time this has happened. In July I raised a [YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-60643), but couldn't really follow it up because the project is not open source, and is a bit complicated to set up, relying on files that have to be built from its (closed source) server project and a custom GRPC/protobuf tool. That and the debugging corollary to Murphy's Law is inevitable.

Adding `--stacktrace` to the gradle command is useless because it decides after it's printed about 87 lines of what led up to the bit of code that caught and rethrew the exception, it should give up and elide the details of what actually threw it in the first place.

Last time I fixed it by doing what I suggested in the Youtrack issue: first I tried [multiplatform-swiftpackage](https://github.com/luca992/multiplatform-swiftpackage), which did work, but was a bit of a nuisance because I had to manually update the package dependency in XCode every time I changed some of the shared Kotlin code. If I can automate that I think it's worth exploring. After that I recreated the project from scratch with new gradle scripts, copied my source files etc back in and that fixed it too. But only for a couple of months as it turns out, and I don't want to have to keep doing that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I fixed it by turning off an option in XCode: Project > Build Settings > Build Options > User Script Sandboxing ("ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING").

Long version:

I tried to guess how to apply that `doNotTrackState` method and added this to `GCAppShared/build.gradle.kts`, just at the top-level at the end:

```kotlin
tasks.getByPath(":GCAppShared:embedAndSignAppleFrameworkForXcode")
    .doNotTrackState("Operation not permitted")
```

This seemed to be the right way to do it; it didn't fix the problem, but I did get a slightly more informative error message:

> error: Sandbox: cp(55680) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/tony/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GCiosApp-caesltabwlltiwgdsytbghwsxekm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GCiosApp.app/Frameworks/GCAppShared.framework

Picking out some of the new keywords led me to an [Apple developer forum post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731041) where I found the answer. The `doNotTrackState` statement is no longer necessary, but by this stage gradle was going a bit crazy, probably because of all the cache clearing etc, so I deleted all the cache and build directories again, including `~/.gradle` this time and logged out to make sure there wasn't a confused gradle-daemon hanging around. The iOS build finally succeeded and I think I'm back in business.